# Java Dice game issue

Tags: java, while-loop, dice

The assignment is to allow a user to input a sum of money as a bet (This number must be greater than 0 bet>=1).

1) Two dice (1-6) are rolled.

2) Their sum is calculated. If this sum is equal to 7, the user wins 4$ and if they lose, the user loses 1$ (Ex: User inputs 5$ as initial bet, wins = 5+4=9$ now–loses = 5-1 =4$ now).

After the user plays, we need to ask them if they would like to play again, and essentially run the program again using a while statement.

I commented out the to print statements in lines 43 and 50 because what would happen is that these two lines would print before the initial question of how much the user would like to enter (Which is why I commented them out).

Now the problem is that after the user inputs the amount he/she would like to bet, the system then calculates the amount they win/lose and prints this. However, it skips over the print statement asking them if they would like to play again. Why is this? I know something is wrong since initially the program was skipping over the first print statement, and going straight to second and third function. Any help?

Thanks!

//Edit: Also if it was not already obvious, I am quite new to program, so please feel free to critique me in any way ^^

```
  //Dice Game
//10/11/14
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class diceGame2
{
    //Instance Variables
    private String play = "yes";
    private int cash;
    private int sum;
    private int winnings;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();


    //Constructor
    public diceGame2()
    {
        cash=0;
        sum=0;
        winnings=0;
    }
    public void game()
    {
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you would like to bet");
        cash=scan.nextInt();
        if(cash<1)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a bet greater than 1$.");
            cash=scan.nextInt();
        }
    }while((play.equals("yes")&&cash<0));
    }
    public int getDice()
    {

        int dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("The number rolled was a" + " " + dice);
        System.out.println();
        return dice;
    }
    public int getSum(int d1, int d2)
    {
        sum = d1+d2;
        System.out.println("Their sum is" + " " + sum + " " + "so...");
        System.out.println();
        return sum;
    }
    public int getWinnings(int sum)
    {
    if(sum==7)
    {
        cash += (4);
        System.out.println("You have won" + " " + "4$.");
    }
    else
    {
        cash -= (1);
        System.out.println("You have lost" + " " + "1$.");
    }
    System.out.println("You current have" + " " + cash  + " " + "dollars left to bet");
    return winnings;    
    }
    public String getPlay()
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again");
        play = scan.next();
        return play;
    }

}//Class




//Dice Game Runner
//10/11/14
public class diceGameRunner
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    String play = "yes";
    while((play.equals("yes")))
    {
    diceGame2 d1 = new diceGame2();
    int dice1, dice2, sum;
    double money;

    d1.game();
    dice1 = d1.getDice();
    dice2 = d1.getDice();
    sum = d1.getSum(dice1, dice2);
    money = d1.getWinnings(sum);
    play = d1.getPlay();
    }


    }
```

}

Comment: I just skimmed over this, so I haven't read it properly (yet), but straight away you have a `while` loop with an unconditional `break` statement, so the loop will only execute once. Don't know if this is your problem, but it looks like a bug. In other words, the `while` is acting equivalently to an `if`.

Comment: You need to post your main method or show the order your methods are called

Comment: @bcsb1001 The only reason I put the break statement is because without it, it would get stuck in the while statement. I was aware that it would only run once due to the break statement, I am just not sure how to get it to leave the loop after the print statement is asked.

Comment: Try to replace `play.equals("yes"))||(play.equals("Yes")` with `play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")&&cash<1` and remove the if and break.

Comment: This is why instructors make you write flowcharts before you code.

Comment: @kharyam I added my main method.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl I did as you instructed, and it works. However, it still skips over the last print statement asking the user if they would like to play again. Any thought? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call the getPlay() method?

Comment: @Sybren In my main function String play; play = d1.getPlay();. It allows me to enter an input (Yes//yes), but when I do nothing happens.

Comment: Is there some code missing in your post or am I blind? Can't find that line.

Comment: @Sybren I didn't add it to my post. I added it now.

Comment: I tested it and I actually get the question to play again

Comment: @Sybren Its not that I do not get the prompt, it is after trying to input anything (yes, Yes, no, etc.), nothing happens. Is it the same for you or does the program work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.
First: You have said that without the break statement your while loop never breaks. This is because the condition will always be true. You never change the condition in the loop always forcing it to be true.

Second: You have "cash =- (-1);" There is an extra - sign in there.

Lastly (More of a side note): You have the loop in your object. This will make it difficult to call any of your methods and make clear code. Try Moving the while loop outside your object and make the object's methods only perform ONE task.

EDIT: Here is sample code of what you should do. It was done in ~ 10 minutes and should be modified to what you want. It is an example on how you should set up the class and do the loop.

The main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler Weaver
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String play = "yes";
        int cash;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.printf("Enter cash amount: ");
            cash = scan.nextInt();
        } while (cash < 1);

        DiceGame game = new DiceGame(cash);

        while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && cash > 0) {
            int dice1 = game.roll();
            int dice2 = game.roll();

            game.calcCash(dice1 + dice2);
            cash = game.getCash();
            System.out.printf("Your new cash amount is $%,.2f%n", (float) cash);
            System.out.printf("Do you want to play again? ");

            play = scan.next();
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of what the class should look like minus other necessary methods:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler Weaver
 */
public class DiceGame {
    private int cash;
    private Random gen;

    public DiceGame(final int cash) {
        this.cash = cash;
        gen = new Random();
    }

    public int roll() {
        return gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    public void calcCash(final int sum) {
        cash += (sum == 7) ? 4 : -1;
    }

    public int getCash() {
        return cash;
    }
}
```

**This is not the answer**. This is example code from your problem. You will have to figure out how to implement exactly what you need.

Note how the class only performs one operation per method. This is just coding convention. Also notice how i ask for cash outside the loop in the main method and calculate inside. I also ask if they want to play again at the end of the method to update the conditional 'play'. Cash is updated through methods in the class.

Comment: After uploading it, I fixed both the break statement and the cash = - (-1). I now have my while as: while((play.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")&&cash<1)) and my cash is cash -= (1);. Both of those were easy fixes. Im just a bit confused on how to move the loop outside of my object.

Comment: I won't give you the answer directly, try making all of your object's methods do one task. If you need to write more methods, then do it. But an object's method should only ever produce one output. After writing that code, you can include any conditionals in the main method. For example, having a do while loop in the main method to play the game while the answer is yes. You can ask for yes at the end of the loop.

Comment: I'm hesitant to write code without seeing what you try first.

Comment: I think I got it. I put my while loop in my main and initialized the String play outside of the loop as "yes". So now the prompt comes up after the game is done, it allows the user to input and reruns the program if it is == yes/Yes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One other question I had is how to set the value cash equal to one value which the system would use over again. In other words, the user inputs a value x the first time. They then lose. So x-1 = cash. If the user wants to play again, they start out with the value x-1 as cash:: or if they won, x+4 as their value as cash, and the system would end when this value reach 0 or when the user wants to stop. Any hints as to how to do this? I tried altering the while statement so when the value was greater than 1, it would skip over that prompt, but nothing has work so far.

Comment: Since it seems like you are asking their cash value once, it would be better to place before the do while loop ever happens. Then the loop parameters would be while "yes" and while cash > 0. Placing it before the loop ensures they xan only enter their cash value once without having to store ut in conditionals.

Comment: I edited my original question to have my new code. I changed the while to a do while – while(play.equalIgnoreCase("yes")&&cash<0) but the system does not store the value cash, and just repeatedly asks for a new value.

Comment: You want to ask for the cash on the outside of the loop. Also, for your loop conditional you want cash> 0

Comment: Im having a bit of trouble doing this. When I move the cash out of the loop, should I make a new function like public int getCash() then under have the printlns asking for the inputs, then the do while under?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time/help! Also thanks for not giving me the answer, but making me find it ^^. I got the output I wanted all thanks to you :).